# how to pass Isolated Storage path

Tags: c#

I would like to get all `JSON` files from a user Isolated Storage location where I am trying to get files through `Directory.GetFiles` method.

Question, how to path for isolated storage?

```
var X= Directory.GetFiles(IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForAssembly().ToString(), "*.json")
```

Comment: I got it working by using like `Directory.GetFiles(IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForAssembly().GetType().GetField("m_RootDir", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForAssembly()).ToString(), "*.json")`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, below solution works for me...

```
Directory.GetFiles(IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForAssembly().GetType().GetField("m_RootDir", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForAssembly()).ToString(), "*.json")
```